# Unable to run batch script successfully from Java

Tags: java, batch-file

The following batch script that works fine if I run it in a batch file (`.bat`). It gets all the files on the SFTP server and downloads to the local folder.

However, if I run this from the Java code, it gets only 4 files. Why is that it stops after it gets the 4 files?

Batch script:

```
winscp.com /log=C:\winscp\logs\winscp_detailed.log /xmllog=C:\winscp\logs\winscp.log /command ^
    "open sftp://root:password@xx.xxx.xx.xx/ -privatekey=""C:\winscp\key.ppk"" -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"" -passphrase=""password""" ^
    "get /home/SFTP/* C:\LocalFolder1\" ^
    "exit"
```

Java Code that executes the above command:

```
public HashMap runExternalProgram_Windows(String Command) {

    String line;

    InputStream stderr = null;
    InputStream stdout = null;

    HashMap _m = new HashMap();

    try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (Command);

        Worker worker = new Worker(process);
        worker.start();
        try {
            worker.join(30000);
            if (worker.exit == null) {
                throw new Exception();                  
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            _m.put("LOG_ERROR_EXTERNAL", "30 second time out...check connection");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return _m;
        } finally {
            process.destroy();
        }

        stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
        stdout = process.getInputStream ();

        String _log_output = null;

        // clean up if any output in stdout
        BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
        while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
            if (_log_output==null) {
                _log_output = line + "\n";
            } else {
                _log_output = _log_output + line + "\n";                    
            }
        }

        brCleanUp.close();

        _m.put("LOG_OUTPUT", _log_output);

        String _log_error = null;
        // clean up if any output in stderr
        brCleanUp=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
        while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
            if (_log_error==null) {
                _log_error = line + "\n";
            } else {
                _log_error = _log_error + line + "\n";                  
            }
        }

        brCleanUp.close();          
        _m.put("LOG_ERROR_EXTERNAL", _log_error);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return _m;      

}


private static class Worker extends Thread {
    private final Process process;
    private Integer exit;
    private Worker(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            exit = new Integer(process.waitFor());
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            return;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the time that the script need to download the files?

Comment: There is no specific time.

Comment: When you calle the join method, you wait only 30 seconds. If the download tales more time, then you throw an exception and then destroy the procesos, aborting the download.

Comment: I have also tried to call just the following code, but that also downloads just 4 files.  `Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (Command)`

Comment: The command need some input argument?

Comment: The input argument is the batch script.

Comment: You have to read the standard error and standard output concurrently, not serially.  You cannot "read all of standard output" and then "read all of standard error";  if you wait for standard output while the program is trying to provide text on standard error, the external program will hang.